# Problem involving rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's call a sequence *semi-arithmetic* if the difference of any two consecutive elements of it can take two different values only.(E.g the sequence $3,7,11,12,16,17,18$ is semi-arithmetic). For the matrix $A$ it holds that the **first three rows** of it form a semi-arithmetic sequence and all the other rows of it form an arithmetic sequence.
Show that in this case $r(a) \le 9$ where $r$ denotes rank.

Comment: I wrote exactly as the problem is given.

Answer (score 1):

Something looks odd about this problem.

**Lemma** If three rows  are in arithmetic progression, then they are linearly dependent.

**Proof**: Let $$r_1=(a_1,a_1+d,..., a_1+(n-1)d) \,;\, r_2=(a_2,a_2+e,..., a_2+(n-1)e) \,;\, r_3=(a_3,a_3+f,..., a_3+(n-1)f)$$

Then

$$er_1=(ea_1,ea_1+ed,..., ea_1+(n-1)ed) \,;\, dr_2=(da_2,da_2+de,..., da_2+d(n-1)e)$$

Thus

$$er_1-dr_2=(ea_1-da_2) (1,1,1,...,1)$$

Similarly
$$fr_1-dr_3=(fa_1-da_3)(1,1,...,1) \,.$$

From here you can easily get a linear combination which is zero. if any of the coefficients is non-zero you are done, and if all the coefficients are zero you can easily prove directly that these three rows are linearly dependent (since the rows are similar but simpler).

**Consequence** Let $A$ be any matrix so that **the first three rows are anything**, and the remaining ones form arithmetic progressions. Then **$r(A) \leq 5$**

Proof: Assume by contradiction that $R(A) \geq 6$. then we can find 6 linearly independent rows, which then contain three rows which form an arithmetic progression. Contradiction